# How to download maven plugins externally?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

After setting up maven when I run `mvn compile` maven automatically downloads plugins for an initial setup. I am using a remote system and I do not have access to download and I would want to add these plugins externally on my own. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

On a system that has Internet access:

1. Install Maven
2. Clear your local repository folder `~/.m2/repository`
3. Copy your project(s) folder(s) to this connected system
4. Perform all the build commands you are going to perform on your project(s) on your remote system

Copy the content of the connected system's local repository to your remote system's local repository.